# Помогите с ошибкой в MySql запросе

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT
    `t0`.`name`,`t0`.`img_id` AS 'id'
FROM
    `store_product` AS `t0`
WHERE
    `t0`.`oid` = :oid
GROUP BY `t0`.`img_id`
```

В последствие выдается ошибка, в которой я не могу разобраться:

PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db_store5.t0.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by in...

Если убрать оператор GROUP BY, то все работает...

Comment: @Jean-Claude, таблица - store_product, алиас - t0

Answer (score 3):

У вас установлена sql_mode=only_full_group_by, поэтому если используете GROUP BY, то в него необходимо добавлять ВСЕ неаггрегированные поля выборки.

Необходимо перед выполнение селекта сбросить sql_mode

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

Comment: Мне нужно что бы в выборку попали только уникальные строки c img_id, если добавить группировать по name, уникальность img_id, теряется. Но спасибо за ответ, пошел гуглить неаггрегированные поля...

Comment: В таком случае зачем вам в выборке name? Конечная цель какова?

Comment: мне нужно любое имя с уникальным img_id

Comment: @СергейДеревянко похоже я наврал в ответе. Проблема в sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Попозже поправлю ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, вот этот пост помог http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by